# matplotlib set_major_formatter creating 2 plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

This excerpt from my code changes the value of the y axis labels from exponential to millions.  Problem is it creates 2 figures.  The first one is an x and y axis with no plot (and the scale of the x axis is used for the y axis as well), and then the 2nd figure is exactly what I want.  It is a double bar graph.
[image]
[image]

I am guessing it has something to do with using f.plot.bar instead of plt.bar but I am not sure. I just want to get rid of the first figure than all will be well.

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
def millions(x, pos):
    'The two args are the value and tick position'
    return '%1.1fM' % (x*1e-6)

formatter = FuncFormatter(millions)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax = tempg.plot.bar(y=['Republican2016Votes', 'Democrat2016Votes'], rot=0, 
color = ['DarkRed','Blue'])

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()
```

Comment: So why not remove the line `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`?

Comment: Silly mistake.  Thanks.  Bit of a learning curve but getting there.